# Teradata: How to create views dynamically from database tables

Tags: sql, teradata, dynamic-sql

I am using Teradata BTEQ version 15.00.  I have the following SQL code.  The dynamical SQL is almost there, but the formet is a little off.

```
.Export Report File = CViews.sql

.Rtitle ''
 .Foldline on
 .Format Off
 .set heading '';
 .set heading off;
 .set UNDERLINE OFF;
 .Omit On 4,5

Select
 CASE When ColNo = 1
 THEN 'Replace View
$view_db_name.VW_'||Tbl.Tablename||' As locking row for access
Select ('
 Else '' END (Title '')
 , Cols.Columnname (Title '')
 , CASE WHEN RevColNo = 1 THEN ')
From $db_name.'||Tbl.Tablename||';'
 Else '' END (Title '')
 , Row_Number () Over(Partition By Tbl.Tablename
 Order By Cols.ColumnId) As ColNo
 , Row_Number () Over(Partition By Tbl.Tablename
 Order By Cols.ColumnId Desc) As RevColNo
 From DBC.Tables Tbl
 Join DBC.Columns Cols
 On Tbl.Databasename = Cols.Databasename
 And Tbl.Tablename = Cols.TableName
 Where Tbl.Databasename = '$db_name'
 And Tbl.Tablekind = 'T'
 Order By Tbl.Tablename, ColNo
 ;
.Export Reset

.Run File CViews.sql
```

Here are the results, but "locking row for access" was cut off, so i got errors when compiling SQL.

```
Replace View  VIEWS_TEST.VW_LOCATION                   As loc
   ID
   LOC_TYPE_ID
   NAME
   LATITUDE
   LONGITUDE
   ADDR1
   ADDR2
   CITY
   STATE
   COUNTRY

   )  From TABLES_TEST.LOCATION                  ;
```

You can see that the "As Loc" was cut off, so i got the following errors:

```
*** Failure 3707 Syntax error, expected something like a 'SELECT' keyword o
 r a 'LOCK' keyword or '(' or a 'TRANSACTIONTIME' keyword between the 'As' key word and the word 'loc'.
                Statement# 1, Info =81
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.
```

I tried different ways try to make it work, but failed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because you have not set the width ...just try by setting width to 200 or something..

Comment: The *missing comma* error can be fixed by  `Else ','`.  Switch to the new V-views, `dbc.TablesV` & `dbc.ColumnsV`, the old ones are deprecated since TD12 and will cut off any table/column names with more than 30 characters. Add double quotes to the table/column names to prevent failure.  And IMHO this task is better suited for a Stored Procedure instead of BTEQ, it's 2015 :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Export Report File = CViews.sql
.set width 200
.Rtitle ''
 .Foldline on
 .Format Off
 .set heading '';
 .set heading off;
 .set UNDERLINE OFF;
 .Omit On 4,5

Select
 CASE When ColNo = 1
 THEN 'Replace View
$view_db_name.VW_'||Tbl.Tablename||' As locking row for access
Select ('
 Else '' END (Title '')
 , Cols.Columnname (Title '')
 , CASE WHEN RevColNo = 1 THEN ')
From $db_name.'||Tbl.Tablename||';'
 Else '' END (Title '')
 , Row_Number () Over(Partition By Tbl.Tablename
 Order By Cols.ColumnId) As ColNo
 , Row_Number () Over(Partition By Tbl.Tablename
 Order By Cols.ColumnId Desc) As RevColNo
 From DBC.Tables Tbl
 Join DBC.Columns Cols
 On Tbl.Databasename = Cols.Databasename
 And Tbl.Tablename = Cols.TableName
 Where Tbl.Databasename = '$db_name'
 And Tbl.Tablekind = 'T'
 Order By Tbl.Tablename, ColNo
 ;
.Export Reset

.Run File CViews.sql
```

Comment: .set width 200 took care of the cutting of SQL issue.  Now i will work on missing "," issue inside the SQL.

Comment: @Dave please paste what did you get as an output now..so that we can improve it.

Comment: @Dave ok i got it...but it will be difficult to generate dynamic views from bteq alone .What i would suggest ,write a shell script to handle the dynamic part.

Comment: Replace View  VIEWS_TEST.VW_WRK_LOCATION                   As loc
king row for access  Select (
   ID
   LOC_TYPE_ID
   NAME
   LATITUDE
   LONGITUDE
   ADDR1
   ADDR2
   CITY
   STATE
   COUNTRY
   ZIP
   CONTACT
   PHONE
   PHONE_SPD
   FAX
   EMAIL
   NOTES
   DEFAULT_CUR
   )  From TABLES_TEST.LOCATION                  ;

   LATITUDE
    $
 *** Failure 3707 Syntax error, expected something like ',' between the word
  'LOC_TYPE_ID' and the 'NAME' keyword.
                Statement# 1, Info =139
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Comment: So the above output missing "," between column names.  I think i can figure it out and post the correct dynamic view tomorrow.  Dave

Comment: You are correct that I have already imbedded database names inside SQL. I used a shell script to pass in the changing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working version on TD version 15.00.
 I added missing "," and change to the dbc.tablesV and dbc.ColumnsV.

```
.os rm CViews.sql
.Export Report File = CViews.sql
.set width 300
.Rtitle ''
 .Foldline on
 .Format Off
 .set heading '';
 .set heading off;
 .set UNDERLINE OFF;
 .Omit On 4,5
Select
 CASE When ColNo = 1
 THEN 'Replace View
$view_db_name.VW_'||Tbl.Tablename||' As locking row for access
Select '
 Else ', ' END (Title '')
 , Cols.Columnname (Title '')
 , CASE WHEN RevColNo = 1 THEN '
From $db_name.'||Tbl.Tablename||';'
 Else '' END (Title '')
 , Row_Number () Over(Partition By Tbl.Tablename
 Order By Cols.ColumnId) As ColNo
 , Row_Number () Over(Partition By Tbl.Tablename
 Order By Cols.ColumnId Desc) As RevColNo
 From DBC.TablesV Tbl
 Join DBC.ColumnsV Cols
   On Tbl.Databasename = Cols.Databasename
  And Tbl.Tablename = Cols.TableName
 Where Tbl.Databasename = '$db_name'
   And Tbl.Tablekind = 'T'
   and Tbl.Tablename not like 'WRK_%'
   and Tbl.Tablename not like 'ZZ_%'
 Order By Tbl.Tablename, ColNo
 ;
.Export Reset

.Run File CViews.sql
```